# How to decode [Object object] in laravel api?

Tags: laravel, api

My scenario is, I get objects in request array in laravel api, which one echo display as;

```
[Object object]
```

From frontend it is being set in the format:

```
{"user":{ 'id': 2, "name": "xyz", "auth_token": "...", ......}}
```

I want to read this data from request, but I have tried following ways and nothing worked

```
json_decode($request->user)
serialize($request->user)
array($request->user)
```

Eerything is just outputting either [Object object] or null. Any insights?

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode($request->all())`?

Comment: Try `dump($request->user);`

Comment: If your backend is receiving `[Object object]` then you can't do anything about it. The front-end must have sent it wrongly. You need to fix the front-end to send a JSON encoded string instead.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Still the output is "[Object object]"

Comment: Can you provide code for context here? Is it a form sending the data, or is it an AJAX post? What's the backend code look like?

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving more than one users data in array after decoding it make a foreach loop to get the values of objects.

```
$users = json_decode($request->user);
foreach($users as $user) {
   $user_id = $user['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possiblities. First, consider, you can get data encoded with formdata method. So, you won't have to decode the JSON anymore. So, make sure you are getting data as stringified JSON, not formdata encoded.
Second point is, you don't have access to user directly, if data is stringified. So, first, you should decode string and then, you can get user property from the decoded object.